# How to get the index of the value with the smallest difference?

Tags: java, arrays, minimum

```
int[] b = new int[4];
int min = 10000;
int index = 0;
b[0] = arr[0][0]; //b[0]=> 
b[1] = arr[1][0]; //b[1]=> 
b[2] = arr[2][0]; //b[2]=> 
b[3] = arr[3][0]; //b[3]=> 

for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  if(b[i]>r)
    b[i]=b[i]-r;
  else
    b[i]=r-b[i];
  if (b[i] < min) {
    min = b[i] ;
    index = i;
  }}
return index;
```

I want to find the index which is closest to my number r. 
eg where the delta is smallest
can anyone help me ?

**here an example: b[0]=1, b[1]=2,b[2]=3,b[3]=4       r=5 ---> smallest difference is 1 (5-b[3]) so the index i want is 3.**

Comment: *index closest to my number* What is your number? *where delta is smallest* What is delta?

Comment: here an example: b[0]=1, b[1]=2,b[2]=3,b[3]=4       r=5 ---> smallest difference is 1 (5-b[3]) so the index i want is 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems: You are not setting the new min right, and you are not setting the new index right.

```
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  if (b[i]-r < min)
    min = b[i];
  index = i;
}
```

You need to include - r in the new min, and you need to put `index = I;` in the same block, or else index will always be b.length - 1

```
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  var dist = Math.abs(b[i]-r);
  if (dist < min) {
    min = dist;
    index = i;
  }
```

}